# R Defining Function in Matrix-Form

Tags: r, function, matrix

I'd like to define a function in R which contains parameter verctors and matrices. Is it possible to define such a function in matrix form so that one does not need to develop the function in order to code it? 
Example: I would like to code the function below, maintaining the matrix form

Equation (1)

> c(w) = c' * w + (1/2) * w' * D * w

where

c is a (3X1) parameter vector with c = (c1 c2 c3)'

```
c = c("c1", "c2", "c3")
```

w is a (3X1) data vector with w = (w1 w2 w3)'

```
w = c("w1", "w2","w3")
```

D is a (3X3) quatratic parameter matrix with

```
         |dLL|dLK|dLM|
 D =     |dKL|dKK|dKM|
         |dML|dMK|dMM|

D = matrix(c("dLL","dLK","dLM","dKL","dKK", "dKM", "dML", "dMK","dMM"), nrow=3, ncol = 3)
```

now, I tried to do something as the following:

```
c_f1 <- function(c, w, D) {
  D = matrix(c("dLL","dLK","dLM","dKL","dKK", "dKM", "dML", "dMK","dMM"), nrow=3, ncol = 3)
  c = c("c1", "c2", "c3")
  w = c("w1", "w2","w3")
  t(c) %*% w + 0.5 * t(w) %*% D %*% w
}
```

With the objective to take a partial derivative with respect to w1 as follows (which clearly does not work)

```
library(Deriv)
Deriv(c_f1, "w1")
```

An example that works but that I tried to avoid: 
When developping equation (1) (multiplying the vectors and matrices) we get the function below (which is a composed scalar product)

```
c_f2 = function(w1,w2,w3, c1, c2,c3,dLL,dLK, dLM,dKL,dKK, dKM, dML,dMK,dMM){ 
  c1 * w1 + c2 * w2 + c3 * w3 + 
  (1/2) * (dLL * (w1*w1) +  dLK*(w1*w2) + 
  dLM * (w1*w3) +  dKL * (w2*w1) + dKK*(w2*w2) +
  dKM * (w2*w3) +   dML * (w3*w1) + dMK*(w3*w2) + dMM * (w3*w3)) }
```

Here the following comand works perfectly:

```
Deriv(c_f2,"w1)
```

As equation (1) can take much more complicated forms as presented here, I wish to code equation (1) in matrix form so that we do not need to code the developed function (since less error-prone), however, allowing for partial derivatives with respect to its arguments by `Deriv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
c <- 1:3
w <- 4:6
D <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)

c' * w + (1/2) * w' * D * w

myfun <- function(c, w, D) {
            t(c) %*% w + 0.5 * t(w) %*% D %*% w
        }
      # [,1]
# [1,] 654.5
```

With your function

```
c_f(w[1],w[2],w[3],c[1],c[2],c[3],D[1,1],D[1,2],D[1,3],D[2,1],D[2,2],D[2,3],D[3,1],D[3,2],D[3,3])
# 654.5
```

Comment: The thing is here that  you've chosen numeric arguments for c, D and w. I need characters as arguments such that c = (c1,c2,c2) , w = (w1,w2,w3) and the same for the matrix D. This is as I also wish to derive later c_f, for example, with respect to w1 applying Deriv(c_f, "w1"). Is there away to code the function including characters in order to allow for partial derivations?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to edit your original post to indicate this, and provide an example of the output you expect. It'd help to avoid answers which seem to answer your question but don't solve your specific issue